# In loop, use {i} as text, or change columns names in a loop/lapply

Tags: r

I need to change the columns names for several dataframes that have the same name structure. I would like to use a loop, but I keep having the same problems. So I am open to use lapply or whatever:

This is what I want:

```
colnames(gom2)<-c(paste("d2", colnames(gom2),sep="_"))
colnames(gom3)<-c(paste("d3", colnames(gom3),sep="_"))
colnames(gom4)<-c(paste("d4", colnames(gom4),sep="_"))
colnames(gom5)<-c(paste("d5", colnames(gom5),sep="_"))
colnames(gom6)<-c(paste("d6", colnames(gom6),sep="_"))
```

This is my attempt:

```
 for (i in 2:6){
    colnames(gom{i})<-c(paste("d{i}", colnames(gom{i}), sep="_")
    }
```

I know this code is mistaken but I just can't get the {i} as text to work with it. I am open to any solution using anything as long as it is intuitive. I have seen other solutions, and tried, but have not had much success, and can't understand what they are doing.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would try something like this:

```
for (i in 2:6){
    df<- paste0("gom", i)
    colnames(eval(parse(text=df)))<- paste("d", i, colnames(eval(parse(text=df))), sep="_")
}
```

We use `paste0` to create the name of the dataframe for each `i`. Then the functions `eval` and `parse`, first parse the character vector, i.e. `df` in this case, and then evaluate it.

Btw I assume that `gom{i}` is intended to mean `gom2, gom3` etc, and `d{i}` is supposed to call `d1, d2` etc, but it's not going to work.

Answer (score 0):

This may do what you need.

```
for (i in 2:6){
  temp <- get(paste0("gom",i))
  colnames(temp) <- paste0("gom",i,"_", colnames(temp))
  assign(paste0("gom",i), temp)
  rm(temp)
}
```